# Subscript out of limit error while using arrays in Pl/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

The following program accesses arrays in PL/SQL, however when I execute the procedure, it gives me a subscript outside limit error. Why does this happen? I don't see anything wrong with this procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ANALYSIS
IS
CURSOR EMPLOYEES IS
 SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;
CURSOR BILLS IS
 SELECT * FROM BILL;
WORKER EMPLOYEE%ROWTYPE;
CASH BILL%ROWTYPE;
TYPE SALARY IS VARRAY(4) OF NUMBER(5);
SALARIES SALARY;

BEGIN
 SALARIES:=SALARY(1,1,1,1);
 SALARIES.EXTEND(4);
 OPEN EMPLOYEES;
 OPEN BILLS;
 LOOP
  FETCH EMPLOYEES INTO WORKER;
  EXIT WHEN EMPLOYEES%NOTFOUND;
  IF WORKER.BRANCHID=1 THEN 
   SALARIES(1):=SALARIES(1)+WORKER.SALARY;
  ELSIF WORKER.BRANCHID=2 THEN 
   SALARIES(2):=SALARIES(2)+WORKER.SALARY;
  ELSIF WORKER.BRANCHID=3 THEN 
   SALARIES(3):=SALARIES(3)+WORKER.SALARY;
  ELSIF WORKER.BRANCHID=4 THEN 
   SALARIES(4):=SALARIES(4)+WORKER.SALARY;
  END IF;
 END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but why do you use a LOOP, when a single `SELECT .. GROUP BY` would suffice?

Comment: I intend to process it further. And I am new to sql :P
I am not understanding how you would use a `SELECT .. GROUP BY`

Comment: `SELECT branchid, SUM(salary) AS salary FROM employee GROUP BY branchid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created an array SALARY that can have a maximum of 4 elements:

```
TYPE SALARY IS VARRAY(4) OF NUMBER(5);
```

Then you have populated with 4 elements:

```
SALARIES:=SALARY(1,1,1,1);
```

Then you have tried to extend it by another 4 elements, i.e. to 8 elements:

```
SALARIES.EXTEND(4);
```

That is where you get the error:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2  TYPE SALARY IS VARRAY(4) OF NUMBER(5);
  3  SALARIES SALARY;
  4  BEGIN
  5   SALARIES:=SALARY(1,1,1,1);
  6   SALARIES.EXTEND(4);
  7  END;
  8  /
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06532: Subscript outside of limit
ORA-06512: at line 6
```

You don't need the EXTEND line.

NB A couple of other points:

1. Since you initialise the array values to 1 your totals will end up 1 higher than they should be?
2. Why not select BRANCHID, SUM(SALARY) rather than manually adding up in a loop?

Comment: Oh, okay! I was trying out some things just now and it struck me that as I was increasing the number of elements in the array the error vanished